# Find a bijection such that half circles will be mapped to segments of straight lines in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Let $\Bbb S^2 =${$(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=1$}. Find a bijection $T$ from $H=$ {$(x,y,z) \in \Bbb S^2 :z>0$} to $\Bbb R^2$ such that the segments of halfcircels in $H$ will be mapped on segments of straight lines in $\Bbb R^2$.

I was thinking about putting a plane on the northpole of $H$ and imagining some sort of light beams coming out of $(0,0,0)$ who are going to that plane. But I'm not sure how to find a real bijection who does that.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) might be helpful to begin.

Comment: Hint: Look for stereographic projection. Project from north pole to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a line connecting north pole with the point on $S^2$. Intersect it with $\{ z=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is $\mathbb{R}^2$.